# Seamless JQuery marquee/ticker

Tags: jquery, marquee, ticker

I found code posted by a user on here for a seamless jQuery marquee/ticker. I've modified it to start and stop when scrolled over/scrolled out of, but it often lags once the user scrolls out. It never completely stops, but the speed at which the ticker scrolls is sometimes 1/10 of its original speed. I've sped it up so it's easier to see this lagging. Anyway, if someone has any idea of how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

### jQuery

```
 $(function() {
  var marquee = $("#scroller");
  marquee.css({"overflow": "hidden", "width": "100%"});

  // wrap "My Text" with a span (IE doesn't like divs inline-block)
   marquee.wrapInner("<span>");
  marquee.find("span").css({ "width": "49%", "display": "inline-block", "text-align":"center", "padding-right":"1%" });
  marquee.append(marquee.find("span").clone()); // now there are two spans with "My Text"

   marquee.wrapInner("<div class='scrolling'>");
  marquee.find("div").css("width", "200%");

  var reset = function() {
       $(this).css({"margin-left":"0%"});
       $(this).animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 500, 'linear', reset);
  };

  reset.call(marquee.find("div"));

  marquee.find("div").bind({
mouseenter: function () {
 $(this).stop();
 if($(this).css("margin-left") == "-"+$("#scroller").width() + "px") $(this).css("margin-left", "0%");
},
mouseleave: function() {
 $(this).stop().animate({ "margin-left": "-100%" }, 500, 'linear', reset);
}
});
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="scroller">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. &mdash; <a href="#">Username</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 </div>
```

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 1):

glad you found an adequate reply however it seems utterly complex and new users looking for a similar solution will most undoubtedly get confused unless they are fairly knowledgeable in javascript. A similar jQuery plugin with all the funcionality; ticker stop and start callbacks, automatic pause on mouse over to allow you reading clearly/clicking on the right item. And seamless transition with full control of direction and speed. You might want to look at the [jQuery webTicker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/) this is a free to use plugin so enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer lies in the way JQuery manages memory in the .clone() and .remove() calls.  There's a very good discussion at:

[jQuery memory leak with DOM removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462649/jquery-memory-leak-with-dom-removal/)

Further details and a workaround are available at:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/severe-memory-leak-with-clone

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually. I found the problem a few days after posting. Basically, "animate" was recalled at the same speed whenever it stopped. So if it had 5000px to scroll or 5px to scroll it would do it in 500ms. I rewrote the code to factor a new speed depending on where the scroller was stopped. It works flawlessly now :).