# memory leak with jquery remove()?

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery memory leak with DOM removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462649/jquery-memory-leak-with-dom-removal)

I created a simple javascript code snippet to test memory leak.

```
function createDom(howmany)
{
    var i;
    var el;
    var body = $("body");
    for(i=0;i<howmany;i++)
    {
        el = $("<div></div>");
        el.text(i);
        el.addClass('element');
        body.append(el);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    createDom(10000)

});
```

when i opened the file in Chrome, it uses about 20mb. When I move to a new url (about:blank), Chrome clears up the memory.

The problem is that Chrome uses more memory when I execute **$(".element").remove()**. The bigger problem is that the memory stays even if I change the URL.

Am I testing it incorrectly? I almost feel like I should just hide all the element instead of removing them...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462649/jquery-memory-leak-with-dom-removal

Comment: @Sudhir // I tried the OP's function (removeWithoutLeak), but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might be of some help , so posted it.
Methods [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove), [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) check descendant elements for data and clean them. That’s the overhead, but, at least, the memory can be reclaimed. Try using [removeData()](http://api.jquery.com/removeData) and then [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach). Hope it will help in some way.

Comment: // when I use native javascript to remove those elements, the memory doesn't increase, but remains pretty much the same. What do you  mean by "can be reclaimed"? Should I call a function to free up the memory?