# Can removing dom elements with listeners cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="waka_waka">
  <li>Fozzy Bear</li>
  <li>Steve Martin</li>
  <li>John Candy</li>
</ul>
```

... and then an event listener is added with jQuery:

```
$('ul li').click(function() { console.log('waka_waka!!!'); });
```

If suddenly at some point one does:

```
$('.waka_waka').remove();
```

Are those event listeners automatically detached and released?  Or will this actually cause a leak of memory?  Is it best practice for one to remove those listeners prior to removing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the jQuery [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) `remove` also removes all bound event handlers

> In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery
>   data associated with the elements are removed.

However have a look at this question [jQuery memory leak with DOM removal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1462649/384985), it seems like there might have been a memory leak at one point (note that that question is quite old so it should have hopefully been resolved by now).